# R Shiny DT - enter search text programmatically

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Is it possible to enter search box text through code?  Required behaviour is: user enters text into `textInput('search2', "Search 2")` and this text replicates in the DT search box and search is performed on the DT.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textInput('search2', "Search 2"),
    DTOutput('dt')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$dt = renderDT(iris)
  })
```

[image]

I do not want to filter the DT data another way (which I'm doing currently) - specifically I'm looking to use the search box functionality of DT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `datatableProxy` of your DT, which allows to manipulate an existing DT instance. Use the function `updateSearch`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)    

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textInput('search2', "Search 2"),
    DTOutput('dt')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    DTproxy <- dataTableProxy("dt")
    output$dt = renderDT(iris)

    observeEvent(input$search2, {
      updateSearch(DTproxy, keywords = list(global = input$search2, columns = NULL))
    })

  })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @shosaco his answer:

Hide the searchbox of the DataTable by adding the following CSS:

```
.dataTables_filter {
visibility: hidden;
}
```